# Can I attach a variable to a tail command?

Tags: shell-script

Is this possible, if not, is there a better I can do it?

Example:

Number of log entries: 3

```
log=$(home/admin17/folder/data_log)
read -p "Number of log entries" num
cat $log | tail -n $num
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `var=$(command)` notation runs `command` and assigns its output to `var`. Since `home/admin17/folder/data_log` is a file and not a command, that should give you an error:

```
log=$(home/admin17/folder/data_log)
bash: home/admin17/folder/data_log: command not found
```

If you want to save the file name as a variable, you need:

```
log=home/admin17/folder/data_log
```

Then, the rest should work as you expect:

```
log=home/admin17/folder/data_log
read -p "Number of log entries" num
cat $log | tail -n $num
```

Or, avoiding the Useless Use of Cat (UUoC):

```
log=home/admin17/folder/data_log
read -p "Number of log entries: " num
tail -n "$num" "$log"
```

Comment: Note also that the path is relative to user's current working directory. If the user wants to use same file regardless of where they are currently in the directory tree, the path has to be absolute, so probably `/home/admin17/folder/data_log`